# Buying iTunes content from desktop app

Tags: macos, itunes, affiliate

I have a desktop application running on OS X and Windows. I'd like users to be able to buy iTunes content from within the app, and I'd like to earn via the affiliate program.

Is this allowed, and if so, how do I do it? The [documentation](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store.html#apps) states:

> The use of the affiliate program inside apps is perfectly acceptable
>   and in fact encouraged behavior for app developers.

but it's not clear if this only applies to iOS apps, or desktop apps, too. Furthermore, I don't know how to pull it of in practice: It seems I am supposed to open a certain URL*. I believe on iOS, this is intercepted, and the user is taken to the App Store. On OS X (or Windows), it seems that this would flash a browser window before opening iTunes, which I'd like to avoid. I'd like to directly open iTunes with the purchase option. Or do I have to embed a browser frame in my app and use some kind of web interface?

---

*) There is some redirecting, and I can improve the user experience with ['short links'](http://www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/resources/documentation/linking-to-the-itunes-music-store.html#shortlinks), or by [handling the redirection manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa2008/qa1629.html) in the background, but in the end there is always an `openURL` call.

Answer (score 0):

www.apple.com/itunes/affiliates/

the program applies to most content types, links can be on a website or within an app. essentially anywhere a iTunes store is: Mac: iTunes and Mac App Store. and on iOS: app store, itunes store and iBookstore. and Win: Itunes Store.